# Aspnetcore website incorrect culture / efcore query issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a weird culture issue that's affecting my entity framework queries/results when comparing dates.

I use the following code to set my culture info in `startup.cs`:

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

However when a HTTP POST comes in and I check the current culture using:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name
```

it returns `en-US` which is causing my `entity framework core` queries to not be able to compare dates.

With an `en-US` entity framework query all the results come back MM/DD/YY and with `en-GB` results are DD/MM/YY and so when I use a where clause in a query such as:

```
event.DateTimeRead.Date == input.Date
```

...the comparison does not work which I suspect is because of the clash in date formats from the current culture.

Any advice on how to fix this would resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From what I can see the culture is correct on the controller methods, but the repository (which is created using Dependency Injection) has the wrong culture info (not all the time, it's weird).

Comment: Why would culture affect data comparisons?

Comment: When I log the date used to query the data it's in format dd/mm/yy and when I first of all query the rows of data and print the date of each row it's in format mm/dd/yy. I can also query the data in the wrong format mm/dd/yy and it works (more often then not).

Comment: Dates don't have formats or culture so this is just not possible. If the dates are being converted to strings though, you will get issues and should not do that.

Comment: Here is the EF query that I am using

return db.Events.Where(evt => evt.DateTimeRead.Date == selectedDateTime.Date)

It has no string comparison

Comment: Yeah, there's no way culture will affect that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120799/discussion-between-david-hawkins-and-davidg).

Comment: You could be hitting the following issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840183/asp-net-core-1-0-rtm-localization-not-working ...try the answer that was suggested here

Comment: @KiranChalla That wouldn't explain why EF query is not working for a particular culture.